# Juniper router SNMP montioring

Tags: monitoring, nagios, network-monitoring, snmp

I've been asked to write a script that checks the status of all interfaces on a Juniper router using SNMP.  I know how to use SNMP walk and have written a test perl script to retrieve the hostname.

Now I'm looking for a good reference of SNMP variables you can query.  I've found a list at [oidview.com](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/2636/JUNIPER-IF-MIB.html), but that does not include interface name or status.  The name of that MIP says "extension", so I assume it's extending some kind of generic SNMP specification.

What SNMP OIDs can be used to retrieve a list of interfaces and their status (admin down, operational down, up) from a Juniper router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While asking the question the answer became clear (maybe I should ask my question to a stuffed parrot before asking it on Serverfault :))

The JUNIPER-IF-MIB extends IF-MIB obviously, and that includes the names and status.  It can be found here: http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/IF-MIB.html.

I'll leave the question here in case anyone else hits the same problem.